# react There was a syntax error in creating components

Tags: reactjs

react Create components to prompt errors

This is the code.

```
import {React,PureComponent} from 'react';
export default class chainRefeshTool extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

我想输出hello word! 但是页面报错
I want to output Hello word! But the page is wrong.
报错信息如下The error information is as follows:

> ./src/pages/BackStage/ChainRefeshTool/index.js
>
> Line 4:  Your render method should have return statement                        react/require-render-return
>
> Line 5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
>
> Line 5:  Missing semicolon                                                      semi
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Can you show how you are importing this component ?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code, but your import statement is incorrect; it should be:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
```

Then you can simply extend `PureComponent` instead of `React.PureComponent`:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

export default class chainRefeshTool extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

There's also nothing wrong with just using the default React export:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class chainRefeshTool extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with you import statement. It should be as follows

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
```

Moreover, when you are extending PureComponent it should be like this:

```
export default class chainRefeshTool extends PureComponent {
```

This is because you already imported PureComponent as named export from react.
That's why no need to use **React.PureComponent** while extending.